# Two SQLalchemy relationships one produces None the other an empty list: Why?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have the following classes set up to define tables using sqlalchemy:

Project

```
class Project(Base):

    __tablename__ = "projects"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    outputs: Mapped[list[ResearchOutput]] = relationship(
        secondary=proj_output_association_tbl, back_populates="projects", uselist=True
    )
    users: Mapped[list[User]] = relationship(
        secondary=project_association_tbl, back_populates="projects"
    )


    def __init__(
        self,
        pure_id: int,
        title: str,
    ) -> None:

        self.id = id
        self.title = title
```

Output

```
class Output(Base):

    __tablename__ = "outputs"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    users: Mapped[list[User]] = relationship(
        secondary=output_association_tbl, back_populates="outputs"
    )
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    projects: Mapped[Optional[Project]] = relationship(
        secondary=proj_output_association_tbl,
        back_populates="outputs",
    )
    equipment: Mapped[Optional[Equipment]] = relationship(
        secondary=equipment_association_tbl,
        back_populates="outputs",
    )

    def __init__(
        self,
        id: int,
        title: str,
    ) -> None:

        self.pure_id = pure_id
        self.title = title
```

Equipment
class Equipment(Base):

```
    __tablename__ = "equipment"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    outputs: Mapped[list[ResearchOutput]] = relationship(
        secondary=equipment_association_tbl, back_populates="equipment"
    )
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    def __init__(
        self,
        id: int,
        name: str,
    ) -> None:

        self.name = name
        self.id = id
```

I can initialise an instance of `Output` and add `equipment` to it by initialising them and appending to `output.equipment`, as `output.equipment` is initialised as an empty list `[]`.

However when I try to do the exact same approach to set up a project for an output I cannot do it, as `output.projects` is initialised as `None`.

Can anyone explain why this would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with the type hint

```py
class Output(Base):
    ...

    projects: Mapped[Optional[Project]] = relationship(
        secondary=proj_output_association_tbl,
        back_populates="outputs",
    )
```

Try to change it to `Mapped[List[Project]] = ...`